# How to use TransactionScope in .net core framework? I cannot find it

Tags: asp.net, transactions, ado.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .Net Core, and upgrading some code from .Net 4.0 to .Net Core.  How to use TransactionScope in .net core framework? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there is no support for that yet on .net Core. As far I understand from [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2949) github ticket, it's something already implemented but planned for version 1.2.

**EDIT**

As 12/6/2017 this is still not implemented

jimcarley commented on Aug 21

> Support of distributed transactions requires a distributed transaction coordinator on the platform where you are running. For Windows we obviously have MSDTC. But we need to make modifications to the classes and interfaces to allow an alternative distributed transaction coordinator to be "plugged in" and used. Those changes still need to be designed. The idea would be to modify the existing internal classes that use MSDTC to conform to the "pluggable" model.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when v1.2 is being released?

Comment: What else can I use to prevent my old code from breaking?

Comment: @SuperCoder: Other than targeting .NET 4.5/4.6 for the time being or wait, there is not much you can do. Well maybe 1.2 nightlies if there are any yet, but they break often as the libraries get new versions rather quickly, not best thing to choose if you are porting a big project

Comment: Agreed with @Tseng, you can target the "traditional" .net framework and add a preprocessor directive to only use transaction scope if NOT targeting .net core. When `TransactionScope` is available you just remove this conditional code.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this post is older.

But, .netcore 1.2 has changed to .net 2.0 and will be available in the Q2 this year.

probably may 10.

to keep updated just follow the .netcore roadmap in this link

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md

**EDIT**
I founded this documentation about transaction scope, i didn't tried it already.

[System.Transactions.TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-2.0)

Any news i will keep updated here!

Comment: Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How sure are you about May 10th, any source?

Comment: Thanks @totonho

I have +1ed your answer. Though it should have been a comment.

Comment: Is there an update on this?  I have an asp.net core 2.0 app and I'm going round and round trying to get TransactionScope to work.

Comment: it is currently set to 2.1.0 milestone https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12534